# copy database row with all dependency with others Tables

Tags: c#, wpf, database

Hi all I have below mentioned Tables and every Table ID is auto incremented in DB (I can't change this property).

```
    Box_Table
Id  Name    Cost
 1  Box1    100
 2  Box2    175

    Fruit_Table  
Id  Name    Cost
1   Apple   100
2   Orange  75
3   Bannana 25


    Box_Fruit_Table 
Id  Box_Id  Fruit_Id
1      1      2
2      1      3
3      2      1
4      2      2
```

**I am trying to duplicate ROW of Table Box_Table.**

I am trying this in WPF using DataSet by adding one Row to the DataSet and copying
the content of duplicating ROW except ID and doing commiting. After getting duplicated ID
have to update the Box_Fruit_Table.

**Problem I am facing is**: 
As ID is autoincrement in DB, only after commit I will get the generated ID.
Because of this I am not able to update the BOX_FRUIT_TABLE for duplicated ROW.

Comment: Why don't you create a stored procedure for this. I would say that is a much better place to do that sort of work. Database updating has nothing to do with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

do following steps

1- Save in the parent table 'Box_Table'

2- Get the latest id generated

3- Update the Box_Fruit_Table with this new id.

Comment: If Many people are working on same TABLE and doing the addition or copying work. In Step 2: I may not get latest id, it may be somebody's Id.!!!!--->So Can it be possible to lock the Table for user(not admin)?  $LOCK$ Step 1..Step 2 $UNLOCK$ ?